How to print to 3 network printers in LAN from a remote WAN network?
On my LAN I have 3 network printers. 2 printers are connected via StarTech.com PM1115U2 Print servers and 1 printer is directly connected to the LAN as it is a network printer.
All printers are printing from all computers within the LAN but I need to print from a remote network. To do that, I have attempted to configure port forwarding on the LAN router.
The router has one static WAN IP. So to print to 3 different printers from remote network we need 3 different external port numbers.
First I tried with direct networked HP printer having IP 192.168.1.64. HP printers listens to TCP port 9100. So port forwarding on router is External WAN IP to internal IP 192.168.1.64 port 9100.
On a remote computer I installed the printer as network printer giving WAN IP, printer found, driver installed and printer printing normally.
But I need to install 2 more printers. So,  port forwarding on router is modified as External WAN IP port 9101 to internal IP 192.168.1.64 port 9100.
Installing the printer on remote computer as WAN_IP:9101 but the printer is not found, installed the printer manually. Printer status showing as idle but not printing.
I need 3 printers as follows.
WAN_IP:9101 to LAN 192.168.1.64:9100 (HP Network Printer)
WAN_IP:9102 to LAN 192.168.1.65:9100 (HP Printer connected to Print Server)
WAN_IP:9103 to LAN 192.168.1.66:9100 (TSC Thermal Barcode Printer connected to Print Server)
Print servers are LPD servers so I understand that I need to open different ports for LPD. But If the first printer works with WAN_IP:9101 then 2 others can be figured out.
Any idea what am I doing wrong? How this should be done?
Thanks in advance.

Printer communication isn't secure by default, so you definitely don't want to be doing this over WAN without a VPN. The simplest way to do this is to configure OpenVPN as TAP (instead of TUN), as TAP is essentially the same as OpenVPN acting as a second router plugged into the LAN port of the primary router, with the client assigned an IP from the same IP Subnet the main router's LAN interface is using, the same as if the client was connected locally to the LAN. Exposing a printer to WAN makes it exploitable, and there are real world examples of folks doing so with McDonald's printers
